# spatialEco package error: non-conformable arrays

Tags: arrays, r

I’m relatively new to R and am running into issues with the spatialEco package in R. The package is version 0.1-4 and my R version is 3.2.3, 64bit. I am attempting to calculate separability metrics for two classes, Upland and Inundated, where I would like to have x = Upland data and y = Inundated data. However, I get the following error in my code: *“Error in 0.125 * t(mdif) * p^(-1) : non-conformable arrays” (see code below).*

```
mydata <- read.csv("closed_alldates_022616.csv", header=TRUE)
mydata1<-mydata [2:59]
x <- mydata1[ which(mydata1$Inundated==0)]
y <- mydata1[ which(mydata1$Inundated==1)]
separability(x, y, plot=TRUE, clabs=c("Upland", "Wet"))
Error in 0.125 * t(mdif) * p^(-1) : non-conformable arrays
```

Additionally, I thought the issue was that my data for x and y needed to be a vector, as I found when researching ([Non-conformable arrays error in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14791399/non-conformable-arrays-error-in-code)). Yet, I received the same error (code below):

```
mydata <- read.csv("closed_alldates_022616.csv", header=TRUE)
mydata1<-mydata [2:59]
x <- as.vector( mydata1[ which(mydata1$Inundated==0)])
y <- as.vector( mydata1[ which(mydata1$Inundated==1)])
separability(x, y, plot=TRUE, clabs=c("Upland", "Wet"))
Error in 0.125 * t(mdif) * p^(-1) : non-conformable arrays
```

I am not sure why they are non-conformable arrays. I thought that I might need to modify x and y to be matrices of the same size. Right now, the table has 3211 Upland observations and 3012 Inundated observations, each with 58 variables. Is it possible that the differences in the number of observations is causing the issue? Any help would be tremendously appreciated.
Thank you.