# Conversion between covariance matrix and correlation matrix

Tags: r, matrix, correlation, covariance

I have a correlation matrix

```
cor.mat <- structure(c(1, -0.25, 0.11, 0.25, 0.18, -0.25, 1, -0.14, -0.22, 
-0.15, 0.11, -0.14, 1, 0.21, 0.19, 0.25, -0.22, 0.21, 1, 0.53, 
0.18, -0.15, 0.19, 0.53, 1), .Dim = c(5L, 5L))
```

I also have a matrix of standard errors

```
sd <- structure(c(0.33, 0.62, 1, 0.54, 0.47), .Dim = c(1L, 5L))

dim(cor.mat)
#[1] 5 5
dim(sd)
#[1] 1 5
is.matrix(cor.mat)
#[1] TRUE
is.matrix(sd)
#[1] TRUE

cov.mat <-cor2cov(cor.mat, sd)
# Error in sds * R : non-conformable arrays
```

So, the matrices have compatible dimensions, why doesn't `cor2cov` function work for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I don't know where your `cor2cov` comes from. But actually, it is really straightforward to obtain covariance matrix from correlation matrix and standard errors:

```
cov.mat <- sweep(sweep(cor.mat, 1L, sd, "*"), 2L, sd, "*")

#          [,1]      [,2]    [,3]      [,4]      [,5]
#[1,]  0.108900 -0.051150  0.0363  0.044550  0.027918
#[2,] -0.051150  0.384400 -0.0868 -0.073656 -0.043710
#[3,]  0.036300 -0.086800  1.0000  0.113400  0.089300
#[4,]  0.044550 -0.073656  0.1134  0.291600  0.134514
#[5,]  0.027918 -0.043710  0.0893  0.134514  0.220900
```

Yes, **it is just a symmetric row & column rescaling.**

We can verify this by transforming this covariance matrix back to correlation matrix using `cov2cor`, which is exactly your correlation matrix:

```
all.equal(cov2cor(cov.mat), cor.mat)
# [1] TRUE
```

---

**My guess on your `cor2cov`**

If you read [How to rescale a matrix by row / column](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38982077/4891738), you will see there are lots of different ways for rescaling. The `sweep` used above is just one option.

R base function `cov2cor(V)` is using:

```
Is <- sqrt(1/diag(V))    ## inverse of square root diagonal (inverse of sd)
Is * V * rep(Is, each = p)
```

I think your `cor2cov(R, sds)` is written in the same style:

```
sds * R * rep(sds, each = p)    ## `sd` must be a vector
```

If so, `sd` must be a vector, otherwise `"*"` will complain (note, the error message you got is indeed reported from `"*"`).

---

Your argument *"the matrices have compatible dimensions"* is a bogus one. Purely in terms of linear algebra, you need `sd` to be a **diagonal matrix**, so that you can do:

```
sd %*% cor.mat %*% sd
```

But row / column rescaling is never done by matrix computations as this is too expensive.

Answer (score 3):

By definition of correlation and covariance matrix, you can simply do this:

```
cov.mat <-  cor.mat * matrix(outer(sd, sd), nrow=5, byrow=TRUE)   

cov.mat
          [,1]      [,2]    [,3]      [,4]      [,5]
[1,]  0.108900 -0.051150  0.0363  0.044550  0.027918
[2,] -0.051150  0.384400 -0.0868 -0.073656 -0.043710
[3,]  0.036300 -0.086800  1.0000  0.113400  0.089300
[4,]  0.044550 -0.073656  0.1134  0.291600  0.134514
[5,]  0.027918 -0.043710  0.0893  0.134514  0.220900
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I might have found an answer on another post: [Non-conformable arrays error in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14791399/non-conformable-arrays-error-in-code)

When I treat sd matrix as vertor, it works (I hope, it's correct?)

```
sd = as.vector(sd)
cov.mat <- cor2cov(cor.mat, sd)
```

Thank you and please let me know if this operation makes the results not equivalent to what I was initially asking about.